# Is there no straightforward way to display a separate second level using wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: menus

I'm migrating a site from another CMS to Wordpress and am writing a tutorial on it alongside.

Wordpress has simple and straightforward solutions to most of the basic features from that CMS that I need to replicate. One big exception seems to be multi-level menus.

I need to display a primary menu level ("About" being the selected item here):

```
HOME  ABOUT  PRODUCTS  BUY CONTACT 
        ^
```

and, in a separate container, the secondary level:

```
 ABOUT US   HISTORY   PEOPLE    AWARDS
     ^
```

I've done a lot of research on how to do this using `wp_nav_menu()`. There are workaround solutions out there, like [this WP.SE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225542/how-to-display-submenus-on-page-based-on-referring-top-level-parent) and  [wp_nav_menu_extended](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-nav-menu-extended/), which is more or less the same approach in plugin form. Those solutions hack into `wp_nav_menu()` and filter out the elements that aren't in the current context.

These approaches did not work 100% for me: they wouldn't reliably filter out the right elements on every type of page.

Then there's [Advanced Menu Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-menu-widget/#developers) that does exactly what I need, but I'd like not to have to use a `wp_nav_menu()` replacement that may not have other features it has. (Also I'm not sure how to call it from within the theme's code - I absolutely would want to hard-wire this.)

The approach I'm using right now is to display the entire menu, then filter out the elements that aren't part of the current second level using CSS - but that feels clunky, too, and I'm hesitant to recommend this in a professional tutorial.

Is there no straightforward approach to this that just augments `wp_nav_menu()`?

Comment: The "canonical" approach to this is a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14039/73). That let's you change the entire tree, the output and even the sorting … and you are still in the "WordPress API". You can pass the current page's `WP_Post` object into the constructor for later use. See also the tag [tag:walker].